# Specifying the context of columns in a constraint

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I'm using sqlite3. I'd like to be able to make a constraint that ensures that a date range does not overlap an existing date range. If they do overlap it's ok aslong as the foobarId is not the same. My problem is how do you specify the context in the example code I have given below (I've resorted to prefixing `query.` as attempt to show the context)? I'm not even sure if this is at all valid, I'm guessing this would be more appropriate in my python code rather than my sql code but nevertheless I wanted to know if it was possible.

**Example Code**

```
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE foobar (
    foobarId INT,
    dateFrom DATE,
    dateTo DATE,
    CONSTRAINT valid CHECK ((SELECT * FROM foobar WHERE (query.dateFrom < dateFrom < query.dateTo OR query.dateFrom < dateTo < query.dateTo) AND foobarId = query.foobarId) IS NULL)
)""")
```

**Example Data**

```
foobarid    dateFrom    dateTo   
1           2013.03.01  2013.03.04   
1           2013.03.04  2013.03.06   
2           2013.03.05  2013.03.07   
3           2013.03.03  2013.03.05
1           2013.03.05  2013.03.07 Invalid
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In an expression `a < b < c`, the comparison between `a` and `b` returns a boolean (0 or 1), whose value then gets compared with `c`.

Comment: I know, I was just reducing the amount of code because that line was getting incredibly long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) says:

> The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.

So you have to register a user-defined function to be called from the `CHECK` expression, or just do the check in the code that inserts the data.

---

Outside a constraint, in the general case, multiple instances of the same table would be distinguished with aliases:

```
SELECT child.id, parent.id
FROM person AS child
JOIN person AS parent ON child.parentId = parent.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `SELECT` in a check constraint; from the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints): *The expression of a CHECK constraint may not contain a subquery.*

This means you cannot do what you want with a CHECK constraint, and you'll *have* to do this in (Python) code instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really appreciate it. I prefer CL's answer to yours simply because they provided a little more information and answered my question about specifying context.

Comment: Not a problem, it is always *your* prerogative to pick the answer that helped you the most! :-)